# A verb indicating neutrality towards another party?

Tags: single-word-requests

A parasitic organism *harms* the other party.

A mutualistic organism *benefits* the other party.

A commensalistic organism [MASK] the other party.

What's the missing verb? "Neither harms nor benefits" is a functional phrase, but I want to indicate "action of no value, positive or negative, being done to other."

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps "[coexists](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coexist) with"?

> 1: to exist together or at the same time
>
> 2: to live in peace with each other especially as a matter of policy